# Regular expression to remove common whole words except those in quotes

Tags: php, regex, string

I've got this regular expression below which removes common whole words(`$commonWords`) from a string(`$input`) and I would like to tweak it so that

1. it ignores those words in double or single quotes (like exact search in google search tab)
2. it remove words starting with hyphen `('-')` but not those inside double or single quotes (like negative search in google search tab)

   `return preg_replace('/\b('.implode('|',$commonWords).')\b/i','',$input);`

thanks

Comment: I would work with `strpos()` instead of regex for this cause regex is an overkill for just stripping specified exact words.

Comment: Be careful with the $commonWords array. If in doubt use preg_quote() on the elements.

Comment: @user2978408 Some input and expected output would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If *only* your "whole words" are to be surrounded by quotes for "exemption" (as opposed to, say, an entire sentence being in quotes), then it's quite easy to do using lookaround assertions:

```
/\b(?<!['"])('.implode('|',$commonWords).')\b(?!['"])/i
   ^^^^^^^^^                                 ^^^^^^^^
```

You can take the extra step to match the two quotes by *backreferencing*:

```
/\b(?<!(['"]))('.implode('|',$commonWords).')\b(?!\1)/i
   ^^^^^^^^^^^                                 ^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you. But my requirement is to use for the whole sentence